# Issue with pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have this question and answer as provided below:

```
int m = 5;

int n = m;

int *p1 = &m;

int *p2 = &n;

m = 10;

p2 = p1;

*p2 = 7;
```

The question asks what are the value of all the following and the answers are:

`m=7, n=5, *p1=7, *p2=7`

This is what I tried:

m is an int of value 5. n is an int whose value is assigned to the value of m, which is 5
and p1 and p2 and initialised to be pointers to m and n.

Then I change the value of m to be 10, so m is 10 and n is 5

Then when I set p2 = p1, both pointers point to m

When I change the variable pointed to by p2 to be 7, n becomes 7, so m = 10, n = 7 and p1 and p2 points to n which has a value of 7.

Therefore:

`m=10, n=5, *p1=7, *p2=7`

what am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: SOLVED

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is on the last line of you answer.
p2 is pointing to the memory address of m, not n.

p2 = p1 is that the memory address stored on p2 will be the address store in p1 that is the memory address of m.

n never change. *p2 = 7; happen after p2 = p1, when p2 is the memory address of m.

Comment: Ok, I think it makes sense now. When I set p2 = p1, both pointers point to m, so when I change the variable pointed to by p2 to be 7, m becomes 7 while n is unaffected, so m = 7, n = 5 and p1 and p2 points to n which has a value of 7. Thanks!

Comment: yes that is good. Please set the answer as correct on the mark on the botton of the votes.

Answer (score 2):

p1 and p2 both point to m. Therefore, the value of *p1 and *p2 is the value of m, which is 7. If you change the value of the variable your pointer is pointing to, the pointer will still point to it.

Comment: Hmm, ok, what about m? It was changed to 10, why did it become 7?

Comment: @TeoZec: don't you mean _m_ instead of _n_?

Comment: Both m and n don't have the right value, basically.

Comment: @mouviciel yes, of course. I mistyped it. I'm really sorry. I'll correct it

Comment: @user3717271 I'm sorry, there was an error in my answer. Try reading it now.

Answer (score 2):

Of the variables, say "x is ...", of the pointers say, "... points to x", and when dereferencing say "(the thing x points to) ...".  Then the sequence of operations can be said to be:

- m is 5
- n is 5
- p1 points to m
- p2 points to n
- m is 10
- p2 points to m (because p2 gets the value of p1)
- ( the thing p2 points to [m] ) is 7

Now look at the answers you have and see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You say: *When I change the variable pointed to by p2 to be 7, n becomes 7*

But you also say, just before: *Then when I set p2 = p1, both pointers point to m*

I see a contradiction here.

Comment: I was just editing it when this was posted. I think I have fixed it. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I hope this might shed some light

```
int *p1 = &m;
int *p2 = &n;
m = 10;
p2 = p1;
*p2 = 7;

int m = 5;

  +-----+
m |  5  |
  +-----+

int n = m; // copy value, m and n are in two diff places

  +-----+
n |  5  |
  +-----+

int *p1 = &m; // set pointer to m

        +-----+
p1 -> m |  5  |        
        +-----+

int *p2 = &n; // set pointer to n

        +-----+
p1 -> m |  5  |        
        +-----+

        +-----+
p2 -> n |  5  |        
        +-----+

m = 10

        +-----+
p1 -> m |  10 |        
        +-----+

        +-----+
p2 -> n |  5  |        
        +-----+

p2 = p1        

        +-----+
p1 -> m |  10 |        
        +-----+
       /     
p2  --+

*p2 = 7

        +-----+
p1 -> m |  7  |        
        +-----+
       /     
p2  --+
```